# rails routing ambiguity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Whats the diffrence between:

```
http://localhost:3000/courses/edit.2
and 
http://localhost:3000/courses/edit?id=2
```

Its produced by <%= edit_courses_path(course) %>

and link_to( { action: :edit, id: course.id } ) respectively

```
http://localhost:3000/courses/edit.2 # This link does not work
http://localhost:3000/courses/edit?id=2 # This link works
```

What can I do to make both of these links work?

Comment: It's a member route, so it should be:

`edit_course_path`

Note it's not pluralized.

Answer (score 5):

Neither is a Rails [resourceful route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default). A resourceful edit route would be achieved with:

```
resources :courses
```

And then you can use the path helpers that are automatically generated (view with `rake routes`) to create a link:

```
<%= link_to "Edit course", edit_course_path(course) %>
```

Producing a link to `/courses/2/edit` for instance, with `params[:id]` being set to 2. Note the singular in `edit_course_path` compared to your `edit_courses_path`.

The reason your version produced `/courses/edit.2` is because route helpers that do not have a dynamic segment take the first parameter as the format, so you're telling it that the format is "2" (as opposed to xml, json, pdf, etc).

Answer (score 0):

**Routes**

As a rule of thumb, each time you create a route, you'll be well advised to use the Rails [route path helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers) (as you did with `edit_courses_path`)

The problem you have (with `/edit.2`) is most likely that your route is not defined correctly (hence Rails will just append the object's ID to the end of the URL

--

You need to appreciate that [Rails' routes are resource-orientated](http://guide.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)

This means that every "route" you create *should* be based around a "resource" (data object), which is why the Rails routing structure recommends the use of the `resources :controller` directive:

[image]

---

**Your Code**

To explain your issue, if you don't have an `edit` route in place, you'll typically get the `edit.2` problem. The solution will be to make sure you use `resources :courses` in your routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :courses #-> will create domain.com/courses/2/edit
```

The next step is to ensure you're able to call the route correctly, which is best done by looking at the routes using the `$ rake routes` command - which will give you the correct path to use